# Can login to MySQL database from Joomla, but not PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, authentication, joomla, phpmyadmin

I have a joomla website and in its configuartion file it is set to connect to localhost with username xxxx and password xxxx.

I setup a phpmyadmin installation and in its config i can see the MySql authentication information. And it's connecting to 'localhost' server.

But when I try to login in phpmyadmin it rejects me.

What could it be? Can MySQL be restricted to only accept joomla or something?

Answer (score 0):

The username and password you set in the Joomla configuration file are not the same as the PHPMyAdmin username and password. They configuration file details are for connecting to the actual database.

The default details for PHPMyAdmin are the same as you cPanel details.

Only other thing I can recommend is talking to your host.